# Surjectivity of map between finitely generated $A$-modules.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a local ring and $f: M\rightarrow N$ be a map of finitely generated $A$-modules. Let $f_{\mathfrak{m}}$ be the induced map from $M\otimes A/\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow N\otimes A/\mathfrak{m}$. Assume that $f_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is surjective. I want to show that $f$ is also surjective.

**Attempt:** Let $x_{1},...,x_{k}$ be generators of $M$ and $y_{1},...,y_{l}$ be generators of $N$. Now let $n\in N$, then $n = \sum_{i=1}^{l}a_{i}y_{i}$ for some $a_{i}\in A$. We can consider the element $(\sum_{i=1}^{l}a_{i}y_{i}\otimes 1)\in N\otimes A/\mathfrak{m}$. By surjectivity of $f_{\mathfrak{m}}$ we have that there exists $\sum_{j=1}^{k}b_{j}x_{j}\otimes \overline{a}\in M\otimes A/\mathfrak{m}$ such that $f_{\mathfrak{m}}(\sum_{j=1}^{k}b_{j}x_{j}\otimes \overline{a}) = (\sum_{i=1}^{l}a_{i}y_{i}\otimes 1)$. Then we must have $f(\sum_{j=1}^{k}b_{j}x_{j})\otimes \overline{a} = (\sum_{i=1}^{l}a_{i}y_{i}\otimes 1)$. From here I am stuck.

Comment: Nakayama looks useful here; use that $M \otimes A/m \cong M/mM$.

Comment: Let me recommend starting only with a minimal generating set of $M$, say $x_1,\dots,x_k$ and trying to show that $f(x_1),\dots,f(x_k)$ generate $N$. As LetGBeTheGraph mentioned, the two keys here are the natural identification $M \otimes A/\mathfrak{m} \to M/\mathfrak{m}M$ and Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: Im able to prove that this isomorphism holds. Consequently one finds that the induced map $\overline{f}:M/\mathfrak{m}M\rightarrow N/\mathfrak{m}N, m+\mathfrak{m}M\mapsto f(m)+\mathfrak{m}N$ surjective. Thus $f(M) + \mathfrak{m}N = N$. But then since $N$ is finitely generated $A$-module and $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{R}$, Nakayama implies that $f(M) = N$ if $f(M)$ is a submodule of $N$. But I dont see why this is the case, since I didn't assume $f$ to be an $A$- module homomorphism.

Comment: @JanBakfiets1 When you say "map of finitely generated $A$-modules" this means $f$ is a morphism in the category of finitely generated $A$-modules, that is to say, an $A$-module homomorphism. Indeed, you must assume $f$ is a homomorphism for this question to make sense.